# IBM Worklight 6.0 is confusing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I was using IBM worklight 5.6 earlier but just updated latest 6.0. Right now thinkin why I updated, earlier was good. Really lots of weird things happened in the worklight project.
App descriptor is changed, I wonder where i'm going to change the server IP ? And I also got to know that 6.0 is having some new Geo location toolkit. Where is that unable get it or did not find a way to get it. No proper doc available to me, I have done a lot google on it. If anyone is having any info regarding this ?

Comment: Do you have a question?  This sounds like whining to me.  Have you [read the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html)?

Comment: Haters gonna hate @mikerott

Answer (score 2):

Build for remote server; right click the app, run as > build for remote server to change the connection hostname:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_transporting_the_app.html?resultof=%22%72%65%6d%6f%74%65%22%20%22%72%65%6d%6f%74%22%20%22%73%65%72%76%65%72%22%20

Geolocation (location services):
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_overview_location_services.html?resultof=%22%67%65%6f%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%67%65%6f%6c%6f%63%22%20

The rest of the docs:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp